# getting the value of a textbox when user enters the name/id of the field

Tags: javascript, jquery

Using jquery to get the value of a textbox.

BUT

i need to enter the id of the textbox, then use that value to get the value of the textbox using jquery.

```
var tt = $("#fieldname").val()
```

that works

now how do i enter the fieldname at runtime, and get jquery to execute the val command as if it was hard coded?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a few ways that you could do this. One way is to listen to one of the keyboard or change events on the textbox you enter the id into, to help determine when the input has changed. So for example

`$("#inputText").on("keyup", function(keyupEvent){
    var textboxId = $("#inputText").val();
    var textboxIdValue = $("#" + textboxId).val();
});`

Or another way could be to use a click event with similar kind of logic, so for example

`$("#clickMe").on("click", function(){
    var textboxId = $("#inputText").val();
    var textboxIdValue = $("#" + textboxId).val();
})`

An example for the use case of both can be seen here https://fiddle.jshell.net/xpvt214o/114584/

Comment: var textboxIdValue = $("#" + textboxId).val();    was EXACTLY what i was looking for!!   thank you

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example for you to get started with:

```
<body>
  <p>Type "one" or "two" below</p>
  <input id="search" />
  <input id="one" value="This input is #one" />
  <input id="two" value="And this is #two" />
  <p id="result">No input specified</p>
</body>
```

And the corresponding jQuery code:

```
// Cache jQuery elements for performance and readability
var $search = $("#search");
var $result = $("#result");

$search.on("change", function() {
  var search_value = $search.val();
  if (search_value.length) {
    search_value = "#" + search_value.toLowerCase().trim(); // Sanitise user input
    if ($(search_value).length) {
      $result.text($(search_value).val());
    } else {
      $result.text("Input not found");
    }
  } else {
    $result.text("No input specified");
  }
});
```

This will show the value of the specified input, if it exists.

You can see it in action here: https://jsfiddle.net/jeevantakhar/xpvt214o/114558/